# Display all objects inside a div with getJSON

Tags: javascript, ajax, append, getjson

I'm trying to append all objects from [this Path of Exile API](http://api.pathofexile.com/ladders/Standard?) inside a Div, but keep getting [object object] for the `entries:`  array.

When I check the console via `console.log(index, value)` I can see everything I want to.

What am I missing inside my code to also show all the [object object] arrays from `"entries: "` with their data?

Thanks in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("button").click(function(){
                $.getJSON("http://api.pathofexile.com/ladders/Standard?callback=?", function(result){
                    $.each(result, function(index, value) {
                        console.log(index, value);
                        $("div").append(index + ": " + value + "<br/>");
                    });
                });
            });
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <button>Klick mich!</button>

    <div></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If `value` is an object then try `JSON.stringify(value)` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you are passing an Object when JavaScript expects a string and thus it converts the Object to a string using `toString` method of Object. The `toString` method always returns `[object Object]` and that is why you are getting that error.

Before your `$("div").append(index + ": " + value + "<br/>");` line, add a check to verify if `value` is an Object and if it is, convert it into a string using `JSON.stringify`.

You can use the following code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $("button").click(function () {
        $.getJSON("http://api.pathofexile.com/ladders/Standard?callback=?", function (result) {
          $.each(result, function (index, value) {
            if (value instanceof Object) {
              value = JSON.stringify(value);
            }
            console.log(index, value);
            $("div").append(index + ": " + value + "<br/>");
          });
        });
      });
    });

  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <button>Klick mich!</button>

  <div></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Ahhh I see!
Thanks for the explanation, works as intended - now I can try to get some more overview into it.

Answer (score 1):

If you replace:

```
$("div").append(index + ": " + value + "<br/>");
```

with:

```
$("div").append(index + ": " + JSON.stringify(value) + "<br/>");
```

that should display everything you want. It may be hard to read, with such a large dataset but works nevertheless.

Comment: This worked, thanks a lot! I tried to stringify the value before, but probably used it wrong.